# Very basic Pycharm TKinter error

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, pycharm

I don't understand why it asks for `TKinter` nor why it wont run it. It's as basic as it goes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 7, 9, 12])
plot.show()
```

where my output looks like this (Note: `xxx` and `yyy` are full paths)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "xxx\Plot 1", line 1, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "yyy\Python 3.5.2 (64-bit)\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
_backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
File "yyy\Python 3.5.2 (64-bit)\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
File "yyy\Python 3.5.2 (64-bit)\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 6, in <module>
from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
File "yyy\Python 3.5.2 (64-bit)\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 92, in __get__
result = self._resolve()
File "yyy\Python 3.5.2 (64-bit)\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
return _import_module(self.mod)
File "yyy\Python 3.5.2 (64-bit)\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named 'tkinter'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Works for me on both Linux Mint and Windows 10. I'm not sure what dependencies matplotlib has on tkinter; I didn't see any during the install of matplotlib. Is there anything else in your code that explicitly uses tkinter?

Comment: Matplotlib tries to use the TkAgg backend, which requires tkinter to be present, but doesn't find it. So the fact that it uses tkinter is not surprising since you ask to open a GUI window. But the fact that it doesn't find it is somehow strange, because tkinter should be part of python and installed by default, but that would probably also depend on the actual system. You may try to use a different backend or see if you can get tkinter to work.

Comment: Will try running it from Linux in case it will help. Still very odd.